# How to copy values from previous row and increasing numeric value?

Tags: sql

My SQL table `AgeBand` has

```
Age     Value
95      1
96      1
97      1
98      1
99      1
100     1
```

I would like to expand this table to

```
Age     Value
95      1
96      1
97      1
98      1
99      1
100     1
101     1
102     1
103     1 
...
115     1
```

Goes up to 115 and keep copying the value above.

How should I code this?

Please help! Thank you@

Comment: PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE don't SHOUT at us !

Comment: Since this will be run once, INSERT 101 - 115 by creating 15 insert rows.

Comment: So you just want another 15 rows with Value 1? Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server.....

```
Declare @age int = 101

while @age <= 116
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO AgeBand
    (Age, Value)
  VALUES
    (@age, 1)

  SET @Age = @Age + 1
END
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants age to increase, he wants it to be the same as the previous row, so in this case, all 1's?

Comment: thank you for the comment! I want the "Value" column to stay as 1 and Incrementing "Age" column by 1

Comment: Isn't that what I have done?

Value stays as 1 and the age increases as per your example.

Comment: Well - you could mark as the answer if you're happy with that.
I hope you get what's going on there so as and when you need to extend again you'll be able to tweek and re-use.